# How to draw a graph with background in dark, and vertexes in light?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, plot-themes

I have a graph `gph` as below:

```
gph = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]
```

Currently, the background is white, and the vertexes are blue in color. How can I display a dark background and light vertexes?

The vertexes coordinates are important, while the edges are not important (they can even disappear).

Many thanks!

Comment: `Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, GraphStyle->"BackgroundBlack"]`?

Comment: `gph = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, Background -> Black, 
  VertexStyle -> White]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, GraphStyle -> "BackgroundBlack"]
```

[image]

#### ***... if `gph` is already there***

```
gph = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}];
SetProperty[gph, GraphStyle -> "BackgroundBlack"]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks. How about if `gph` is already there (which is I can't change)?

Comment: @HMC, i updated the answer.